# What is $ symbol used for in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am new to JavaServer Page(jsp) and have been researching this matter, but  I dont get what is the symbol $ mean.Any resources or readings regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$ is used for resolving attributes passed to JSP.
Refer below link to learn basic of JSP (Head first )https://robot.bolink.org/ebooks/Head%20First%20Servlets%20and%20JSP.pdf
or
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html